# MySQL listing MAX() every hour at time from HH: 05 to HH: 59?

Tags: mysql

I need to do mySQL listing MAX () temperature every hour at time from HH: 05 to HH: 59

I have mySQL code:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/3600)*3600) x,
    MAX(rain_1hod)
FROM weather
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%i') >= 5
GROUP BY x DESC
```

timestamp (datetime): 2019-07-21 16:21:00

However, no data will be written if I use a WHERE query. I have also tried another mySQL query for the hourly listing. Although he writes the data after an hour, but as soon as I use the WHERE query to write the data from five minutes, nothing is written.

```
SELECT timestamp, MAX(rain_1hod)
FROM meteodata
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%i') >= 5
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) DESC, hour(timestamp) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Do you have any specific problem with your query except of using wrong quotes (`“..”`)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using 'i%'. However, no data will be written if I use a WHERE query.
I have also tried another mySQL query for the hourly listing. Although he writes the data after an hour, but as soon as I use the WHERE query to write the data from five minutes, nothing is written.

SELECT timestamp, MAX(rain_1hod) FROM meteodata WHERE STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%i') >= 5 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) DESC, hour(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: Please update the questions with this addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is the wrong function to use. To convert a date to string you need [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). I would also use `DATE_FORMAT()` to group by hour:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') x,
    MAX(rain_1hod)
FROM weather
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%i') >= 5
GROUP BY x DESC
```

Instead of `DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%i')` you can also use `MINUTE(timestamp)`.

Comment: Works, thank you very much.

What will mySQL query look like if I want to use the minutes by HH:05 to the next hour HH:04?

Now it works from HH:05 to HH:59 ... but I would like to extend it up to HH:04. Is that it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try `DATE_FORMAT(timestamp - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') x` and remove the WHERE condition.

Comment: We're very close. Now the mySQL query will print the time after hour from HH:05, which is good, but the time ends in the minute HH:06, which I need to end up in HH:04. Once again, thank you very much for your time, you are very clever.

Comment: With `timestamp - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` the range starts at HH:05:00 and ends at HH:04:59. Example: `'17:04:59' - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` is `16:59:59` and will be grouped to `16:00:00`. But `'17:05:00' - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` is `17:00:00` and will be grouped to `17:00:00`.